# ASP.NET MVC Custom User class is clashing with System.Security.Principal.iPrinciapl

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, namespaces

Hey guys I declared my own class User, and when I want to use it, I Include it's namesapce MyProj.Models;

But The System.Web.Security.Principal.iPrinciapl (Controller.User) is getting in the way and making me have to write out the whole path to my class if I want to use it. I.E MyProj.Models.User.DoSomething().

How can I get around this? Give mine priority or similar?

Answer (score 2):

The way I resolve this is to use a using alias:

```
using mUser = MyProj.name.space.User;

public class MyController : Controller {
    public void foo() {
        var user = new mUser(...);
    }
}
```